# WSAAsyncSelect and send from another thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio-2017, winsock, wsaasyncselect

I'm creating a TCP client using C++ and Winsock.
I created a message-only window which will process the WM_SOCKET message, which I registered using WSAAsyncSelect.

My question is the following: I need to send data from another thread (the GUI thread of my app), can I safely call the 'send' function from that thread or maybe do I need to use some locking interface (mutexes) in order to send data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no problem sending from a different thread from the one that receives.

For datagram sockets, you can even have multiple threads sending at once (messages will be interleaved but not intermingled).

For stream sockets, which includes TCP, multiple simultaneous senders could intermingle data, so only one sending thread at a time is recommended.  But even with a one sending thread limit, it doesn't have to be the same as the receiving thread.

Comment: Thank you very much! So if I have understood correctly, I can send and receive data at the same time, but I can't have multiple threads sending at once, right? (for stream sockets of course)

Comment: @winapiwrapper: Yes, that's it.  If you have multiple threads wanting to send, they should use a mutex or critical section to make sure that one data block is fully transferred (at least into the networking buffers, so that it has a firmly assigned range of bytes in the stream) before transferring the next one begins.  But sends can freely overlap receives.